# Jquery Autofill with two parameters

Tags: php, jquery, url, autofill

I know its probably simple as 123 but I'm noob in jquery..
I have a function :

```
 $(function()
 {
  $('#ser').autocomplete('serial.php?tp='+$('#type').val(), 
{   width: 150, });
 });
```

..that passes value of text field  *ser* and drop down list *type* to the page where I'm using query based on those two variables.. that works only with the first var in a drop down list but if i change var in it, it still uses first from the list... Ih other words its not dynamic... 
Also I tried this function :

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#ser").click(function(){
   var tp = $("#type").val();
});
  });
```

which works dynamically, but I can't add var tp to url address in other function (because i'm a noob!)

PLease help

Comment: Your question has me confused. Let me get this straight... You are using jQuery UI autocomplete right? and what are your trying to do? maybe you could post a full example on jsfiddle and just have it alert any calls to your php files. I believe that I can help, but without a more clear example, I am confused on what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks Joseph, but I've sorted that...I'll post the code in case if anyone will have similar question..

Comment: Post your html as well , to make us understand what all these id's are

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution i was looking for:

```
$(function()
 {
  var tp='';
   $("#ser").click(function(){
    tp = $("#type").val();
//alert(tp);
$('#ser').autocomplete('serial.php?tp='+tp, 
{   width: 150, });
  });


  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The autocomplete "source" can be an array, a string or a function. You've chosen to use a string.

When using the string option for the source, the value supplied by the user is appended to the querystring automatically but the rest of the string is static, evaluated only once when the page loads. It is not re-evaluated when the user changes their input.

To make the url dynamic, as you wish, you'll need to use the third option: a function.